# Mosquitto won't start without calling mosquitto -d

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, mqtt, mosquitto, paho

I basically got the same problem as in [this](https://community.openenergymonitor.org/t/mqtt-error-connection-refused/4264/4) post: I'm running a python script on a Raspberry Pi with Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 which connects with a MQTT Broker via paho mqtt, but I get `Connection refused`, **unless** I call `mosquitto -d` before - than it just works fine.

That's what I get when calling the mosquitto status:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ systemctl status mosquitto
● mosquitto.service - Mosquitto MQTT v3.1/v3.1.1 Broker
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mosquitto.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2020-11-28 12:53:33 CET; 20h ago
     Docs: man:mosquitto.conf(5)
           man:mosquitto(8)
  Process: 486 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mosquitto -c /etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf (code=exited, status=3)
 Main PID: 486 (code=exited, status=3)

Nov 28 12:53:33 raspberrypi systemd[1]: mosquitto.service: Service RestartSec=100ms expired, scheduling restart.
Nov 28 12:53:33 raspberrypi systemd[1]: mosquitto.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
Nov 28 12:53:33 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Stopped Mosquitto MQTT v3.1/v3.1.1 Broker.
Nov 28 12:53:33 raspberrypi systemd[1]: mosquitto.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Nov 28 12:53:33 raspberrypi systemd[1]: mosquitto.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Nov 28 12:53:33 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Failed to start Mosquitto MQTT v3.1/v3.1.1 Broker.
```

Whole Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mqtt_test.py", line 20, in <module>
    client.connect(BROKER_ADDRESS)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line 941, in connect
    return self.reconnect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line 1075, in reconnect
    sock = self._create_socket_connection()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line 3546, in _create_socket_connection
    return socket.create_connection(addr, source_address=source, timeout=self._keepalive)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/socket.py", line 727, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/socket.py", line 716, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

From `/etc/mosquitto/conf.d/mosquitto.conf`:

```
 Place your local configuration in /etc/mosquitto/conf.d/
#
# A full description of the configuration file is at
# /usr/share/doc/mosquitto/examples/mosquitto.conf.example

pid_file /var/run/mosquitto.pid

persistence true
persistence_location /var/lib/mosquitto/

log_dest file /var/log/mosquitto/mosquitto.log

allow anonymous false
password_file /etc/mosquitto/pwfile
listener 1883
```

From `/var/log/moquitto/mosquitto.log`:

```
1601020477: mosquitto version 1.5.7 starting
1601020477: Config loaded from /etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf.
1601020477: Opening ipv4 listen socket on port 1883.
1601020477: Opening ipv6 listen socket on port 1883.
1601020533: New connection from ::1 on port 1883.
1601020533: New client connected from ::1 as mosqsub|1315-raspberryp (c1, k60).
1601020675: Socket error on client mosqsub|1315-raspberryp, disconnecting.
1601020862: New connection from ::1 on port 1883.
1601020862: New client connected from ::1 as mosqpub|1333-raspberryp (c1, k60).
1601020862: Client mosqpub|1333-raspberryp disconnected.
1601020978: New connection from ::1 on port 1883.
1601020978: New client connected from ::1 as mosqpub|1344-raspberryp (c1, k60).
1601020978: Client mosqpub|1344-raspberryp disconnected.
1601021092: New connection from ::1 on port 1883.
1601021092: New client connected from ::1 as mosqpub|1579-raspberryp (c1, k60).
1601021092: Client mosqpub|1579-raspberryp disconnected.
1601022277: Saving in-memory database to /var/lib/mosquitto/mosquitto.db.
1601024078: Saving in-memory database to /var/lib/mosquitto/mosquitto.db.
1601025879: Saving in-memory database to /var/lib/mosquitto/mosquitto.db.
1601027680: Saving in-memory database to /var/lib/mosquitto/mosquitto.db.
1601029481: Saving in-memory database to /var/lib/mosquitto/mosquitto.db.
1601031282: Saving in-memory database to /var/lib/mosquitto/mosquitto.db.
1601033083: Saving in-memory database to /var/lib/mosquitto/mosquitto.db.
1601034884: Saving in-memory database to /var/lib/mosquitto/mosquitto.db.
1601036685: Saving in-memory database to /var/lib/mosquitto/mosquitto.db.
1601038486: Saving in-memory database to /var/lib/mosquitto/mosquitto.db.
1601040287: Saving in-memory database to /var/lib/mosquitto/mosquitto.db.
1601042088: Saving in-memory database to /var/lib/mosquitto/mosquitto.db.
1601043889: Saving in-memory database to /var/lib/mosquitto/mosquitto.db.
1601045690: Saving in-memory database to /var/lib/mosquitto/mosquitto.db.
1601047491: Saving in-memory database to /var/lib/mosquitto/mosquitto.db.
1601049292: Saving in-memory database to /var/lib/mosquitto/mosquitto.db.
1601050572: mosquitto version 1.5.7 terminating
1601050591: mosquitto version 1.5.7 starting
1601050591: Config loaded from /etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf.
1601050591: Opening ipv4 listen socket on port 1883.
1601050591: Opening ipv6 listen socket on port 1883.
1601309165: Saving in-memory database to /var/lib/mosquitto/mosquitto.db.
1601309344: mosquitto version 1.5.7 terminating
```

I tried passing username & password in the python test code below, but it still raises the same error, even though the username & password is the correct one (I set it up via

`sudo mosquitto_passwd -c /etc/mosquitto/pwfile pi`.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
 
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
 
def on_message(client, userdata, message):
    msg = str(message.payload.decode("utf-8"))
    print("message received: ", msg)
    print("message topic: ", message.topic)
 
def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    client.subscribe('/home/data')
 
BROKER_ADDRESS = "192.168.178.201"
 
client = mqtt.Client()
client.on_connect = on_connect
client.on_message = on_message
client.tls_set()
client.username_pw_set(username="pi", password ="password")
client.connect(BROKER_ADDRESS)
 
print("Connected to MQTT Broker: " + BROKER_ADDRESS)
 
client.loop_forever()
```

New log file:

```
1606671705: mosquitto version 1.5.7 starting
1606671705: Config loaded from /etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf.
1606671705: Opening ipv4 listen socket on port 1883.
1606671705: Opening ipv6 listen socket on port 1883.
1606671781: mosquitto version 1.5.7 terminating
1606671794: mosquitto version 1.5.7 starting
1606671794: Config loaded from /etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf.
1606671794: Opening ipv4 listen socket on port 1883.
1606671794: Opening ipv6 listen socket on port 1883.
1606671798: mosquitto version 1.5.7 terminating
1606671837: mosquitto version 1.5.7 starting
1606671837: Config loaded from /etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf.
1606671837: Opening ipv4 listen socket on port 1883.
1606671837: Opening ipv6 listen socket on port 1883.
1606671988: mosquitto version 1.5.7 terminating
```

Is there a way to fix this or alternatively, call `mosquitto -d` automatically when the RPi boots?

I tried `sudo systemctl enable mosquitto.service`, didn't work. Neither did deleting the log file.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: A question for https://askubuntu.com/.   Probabale answer here   https://askubuntu.com/questions/815091/how-do-i-start-mosquitto-mqtt-broker-on-startup-in-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: Just saying it doesn't work doesn't give us much to go on. You really need to edit the question to include version numbers for everything and log output from the broker when the client fails to connect. Also India about how you've configured mosquitto

Comment: @hardillb added Raspbian Version and whole error

Comment: I meant the mosquitto version and the logs from mosquitto

Comment: No, I want the content of `/etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf` and an appropriate snippet from `/care/log/mosquitto/mosquitto.log`

Comment: @hardillb done. I don't have a directory called ```care``` though, I assume you meant ```var```, at least that's where my logging file is.

Comment: Delete the current log file, then run the following and add the output and the new log file  to the question `mosquitto -c /etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf`

Comment: I did as you said, but when I run ```sudo mosquitto -c /etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf``` it doesn't do anything - no return, nothing - until I hit ```Ctrl```+```c```. I added the new log file

Comment: I don't see any error, yet your Mosquitto is quitting.  Try upping the log level and see if there is some reason being given for quitting.  http://www.steves-internet-guide.com/mosquitto-logging/

Comment: @JDAllen me neither. Well it works just fine if I don't do ```allow_anonymous false``` so mybe I just remove that. Would that be a serious security issue?

Comment: That depends. If you are exposing your  Mosquitto broker to the Internet, then definitely yes....if its just inside your house or business, probably not an issue ;)

Answer (score 0):

OK, so you mosquitto.conf file includes a password file which will enforce authentication.

> ```
> allow anonymous false
> password_file /etc/mosquitto/pwfile
> ```

Starting mosquitto with just the `-d` option will not use the config file so will not be enforcing username/password requirements. (you can specify the config file using the `-c` command line option)

The most likely reason for the connection refused error is because your python code is not passing a username/password

Comment: Thanks, I added an answer with my test code which passes username & password but it still raises the same error...Maybe I should just put ```allow anonymous True``` in the config file

Answer (score 0):

It's an old post but I'm gonna answer to it for anyone having the same problem.

1. With this line: `client.tls_set()` you are trying to establish a secure line but you are not providing any SSL trusted certificate to the function tls_set.

By removing the line, your code should works (tested it).

If you still want to use TLS protocol this post should help you:
http://www.steves-internet-guide.com/mosquitto-tls/

2. If you still encounter the error, try to add `allow_anonymous true` to your mosquitto.conf and remove `client.username_pw_set(username="pi", password ="password")` on your client to be sure it's not an authentification issue.